# NMaximize with generic domain

Tags: regions, vector

I want to have a function that gets generic domain and function and does maximum on this domain.
For this I tried the following straight-forward code:

```
aa[xa_, ya_] := xa + ya
dom = ImplicitRegion[-3 <= a <= 5 && -10 <= b <= 10, {a, b}]
Module[{mm}, NMaximize[ aa @@ mm, mm \[Element]  dom]]
```

It doesn't work

```
NMaximize::objfs: The objective function {Subscript[mm$86344, 1],Subscript[mm$86344, 2]} should be scalar-valued.
```

If I do
`{x,y} \in dom` etc then it does work. But I prefer to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

aa[{xa_, ya_}] := xa + ya
dom = ImplicitRegion[-3 <= a <= 5 && -10 <= b <= 10, {a, b}];
Module[{mm}, NMaximize[aa@mm, mm ∈ dom]]

(* {15., {mm$4229 -> {5., 10.}}} *)
```

Or with [`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html)

```
Module[{mm}, Maximize[aa@mm, mm ∈ dom]]

(* {15, {mm$4320 -> {5, 10}}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Re your comment below

```
aa2[x_List] := x[[1]] + x[[2]]

Module[{mm}, Maximize[aa2@mm, mm ∈ dom]]

(* {15, {mm$6507 -> {5, 10}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! Why I couldn't access the members any other way. For example `aa[x_]:=x[[1]]* x[[2]] ` or using subscripts (like it suggested)